# Draw ruler grid on image node by cm unit

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to draw a grid on image with cm unit. I know many solution for this topic. My idea right now is try to calculate it as below! I guess should use \n1 and \n2 as foreach up limit (currently use \width and \height macro).

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \def\width{6}
    \def\height{8}
    %\tikzstyle{every node}=[ultra thick, draw]
    \node[anchor=south west,opacity=0.5,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \draw[line width=2pt]
        let 
        \p1=(image.south west),
        \p2=(image.north east),
        \n1={(\x2-\x1)},
        \n2={(\y2-\y1)}  
        in node[anchor=west] at (0,-2) {\Huge \n1,\n2} 
        \foreach \col in {0,...,\height} {
        \foreach \row in {0,...,\width} {
            (0,\col) -- (\width,\col)
            (\row,0) -- (\row,\height)
        }}
        foreach \x in {0,1,...,\width} {node[anchor=north] at (\x,0) {\x}}
        foreach \y in {0,1,...,\height} {node[anchor=east] at (0,\y) {\y}}
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Currently the unit of \n1 and \n2 is pt, maybe I need to convert it to cm unit but I don't how to do it.

My target is use \n1 and \n2 as the foreach up limit instead of \width and \height. so it will match the image exactly!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposal. The conversion is in principle very simple: just multiply by the conversion factor

```
        \n1={(\x2-\x1)*1pt/1cm},
        \n2={(\y2-\y1)*1pt/1cm}
```

However, even though you have now cm, Ti*k*Z will still claim these are points. So you need to politely convert it to admit these are cm.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[pfft/.code n args={2}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{#2}
    \xdef#1{\tmp}}]
    \def\width{6}
    \def\height{8}
    %\tikzstyle{every node}=[ultra thick, draw]
    \node[anchor=south west,opacity=0.5,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \draw[line width=2pt]
        let 
        \p1=(image.south west),
        \p2=(image.north east),
        \n1={(\x2-\x1)*1pt/1cm},
        \n2={(\y2-\y1)*1pt/1cm}  
        in [pfft={\myx}{\n1},pfft={\myy}{\n2}]
        node[anchor=west] at (0,-2) {\Huge \myx cm,\myy cm} 
        \foreach \col in {0,...,\height} {
        \foreach \row in {0,...,\width} {
            (0,\col) -- (\width,\col)
            (\row,0) -- (\row,\height)
        }}
        foreach \x in {0,1,...,\width} {node[anchor=north] at (\x,0) {\x}}
        foreach \y in {0,1,...,\height} {node[anchor=east] at (0,\y) {\y}}
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And you can use this to draw an integer grid as follows.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[pfft/.code n args={3}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{#3}
    \xdef#1{\tmp}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmp}{#3}
    \xdef#2{\tmp}
    }]
    \def\width{6}
    \def\height{8}
    %\tikzstyle{every node}=[ultra thick, draw]
    \node[anchor=south west,opacity=0.5,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \draw[line width=2pt]
        let 
        \p1=(image.south west),
        \p2=(image.north east),
        \n1={(\x2-\x1)*1pt/1cm},
        \n2={(\y2-\y1)*1pt/1cm}  
        in [pfft={\myx}{\mywidth}{\n1},pfft={\myy}{\myheight}{\n2}]
        node[anchor=west] at (0,-2) {\Huge \myx cm,\myy cm} 
        \foreach \col in {0,...,\myheight} {
        \foreach \row in {0,...,\mywidth} {
            (0,\col) -- (\mywidth,\col)
            (\row,0) -- (\row,\myheight)
        }}
        foreach \x in {0,1,...,\mywidth} {node[anchor=north] at (\x,0) {\x}}
        foreach \y in {0,1,...,\myheight} {node[anchor=east] at (0,\y) {\y}}
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]